# DialogFragment's inflated view being reused in next instance

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a dialog fragment with a custom view. The background color of the custom view also changes depending on the passed argument from `newInstance()` method. To make certain that it's really a different DialogFragment instance, I also passed another argument to the `newInstance()` method, the dialog title. The background color can also accept a `null` value, in which case, no background color is set.

Now here is the problem: when I show the dialog fragment with the `null` value passed for the background color the second time, the inflated view still has the background color of the last shown dialog fragment even though the title is already different. Why is the system reusing the last inflated view? Shouldn't the background color be empty? What am I not understanding properly?

**MyDialogFragment.java**

```
public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String title, Integer bgColor) {
    MyDialogFragment df = new MyDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(TITLE_ARG, title);
    args.putSerializable(BG_ARG, bgColor);
    df.setArguments(args);
    return df;
}

...

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    Integer bgColor = (Integer) args.getSerializable(BG_ARG);
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_fragment, null);

    // check if null was passed
    if(bgColor != null)
        ((GradientDrawable) view.getBackground()).setColor(bgColor);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(args.getString(TITLE_ARG))
            .setView(view)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
            .create();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            MyDialogFragment df = (MyDialogFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(MyDialogFragment.TAG);
            if(df == null) {
                df = MyDialogFragment.newInstance("title1", Color.GREEN);
                df.show(fm, MyDialogFragmentTAG);
            }
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            MyDialogFragment df = (MyDialogFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(MyDialogFragment.TAG);
            if(df == null) {
                df = MyDialogFragment.newInstance("title2", null);
                df.show(fm, MyDialogFragmentTAG);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first click of button1 will create dialog and attach it to the FragmentManager.

The click of button2 (second click) will find your old fragment, so df should not be null, and you should not see any dialog.

Maybe your snippet of code is incomplete.

Comment: The code snippet is fine.  The click of button2 on the main activity means that the dialog fragment is already dismissed.  Otherwise, button2 cannot be clicked if the dialog fragment is still shown.  So, df is already null when button2 is clicked, and therefore shows a new dialog fragment.

Comment: Can you share all code? I wrote a little test and it works fine with  `view.setBackgroundColor()`. 
You are right about dismissed dialogs, so there is no need in searching fragments at all, you cannot push button1 or button2 while dialog in focus.

Comment: I did not use `view.setBackgroundColor()` because I'm using a `Drawable` for the `android:background` attribute in xml.  I will make separate project and share code.